# How to declare numpy array of particular type as type in dataclass

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, python-dataclasses

**What I have:**
I am creating a dataclass and I am stating the types of its elements:

```
class Task():  
     n_items: int  
     max_weight: int  
     max_size: int  
     items: numpy.array(Item)  # incorrect way of doing it
```

**What I want to do**
I'd like to declare, that **items** will be a numpy array of obejcts of class "Item"

Comment: There is an open issue regarding type annotations for numpy arrays: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `ndarray`:

```py
import numpy as np

class Task():  
     n_items: int  
     max_weight: int  
     max_size: int  
     items: np.ndarray
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't show that items will be a numpy array of a particualr type of objects

Comment: Hm, I see - I would then consider making ```numpy``` container, as per: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.dispatch.html and force it to take only certain type of objects.

Comment: Well, I've just learned that if you provide a user created class a numpy array data type it'll simply mean dtype=object, as in generic Python object. It answers my question.

Comment: You don't have any native ```numpy``` type with restricted ```dtype```

Comment: Right - but then ```object``` means everything. So it could be either your custom class, or anything else. You can actually force it to take only one type, but that would mean exactly making custom ```numpy``` container

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ndarray` class type:

```
import numpy as np

class Task():  
     n_items: int  
     max_weight: int  
     max_size: int  
     items: np.ndarray[<shapeType>, <convertedNumpyGenericType>]
```

Where `<shapeType>` is the type of values defining the shape of the array (probably `int`) and `<convertedNumpyGenericType>` defines the array data's type. Be careful that you have to "convert" numpy generic types into python ones. You may want to use `np.dtype[<generic>]` with `<generic>` the generic numpy type (e.g `np.float64`)

If you want to set a default value (inside the `field` dataclass function) you have to do as follows:

```
items: np.ndarray[_, _] = field(default_factory=lambda: np.zeros(shape=<int>, dtype=<type>))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [nptyping](https://pypi.org/project/nptyping/) package, which offers type hints specifically for Numpy data types.

Unless you want to create a custom Numpy container, the best you can do is to denote your array as a container of `typing.Any` objects, since support for types beyond the ones mentioned [here](https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/nptyping/blob/master/USERDOCS.md#DTypes) is lacking.

```
from nptyping import NDArray, Shape
from typing import Any
import numpy as np


class Item:
    pass


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: NDArray[Shape["1,2"], Any]):
        self.bar = bar


if __name__ == '__main__':
    item = Item()
    foo = Foo(bar=np.array([Item(), Item()], dtype=Item))
    print(foo.bar)
```

Running this will yield something like

```bash
[<__main__.Item object at 0x7f13f0dd9e80>
 <__main__.Item object at 0x7f13f0dd9040>]
```